# how to locate the sync interval and rewrite it in kubelet.go?

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I want to adjust the [kubelet](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/99d40d3d441ef58eb10ef6ad065b96da3d425523/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go#L1824) sync interval. and it said that was 10s. but i can t find out  where it is or how to change it.

//sync interval is defaulted to 10s.

Comment: Hi @李俊辉, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I find out that the interval is related to the flag --sync-period  of kubelet,it is
 1 min at normal ，and the interval work in the function pod_worker->wrap_up->workqueue.enqueue. So, i have resolved it